# Json schema allOf and object order

Tags: json, openapi, jsonschema

I have a schema, on which I run an operation to generate an xml.
Assume we're working with the following .jsd

```json
{
    "$schema" : "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "$id" : "mySchema",
    "title" : "some title",
    "type":"object",    
    
    "properties":{
        "arbitraryField" : {
            "$ref" : "#/$defs/ArbitraryField"
        },
        "allOfField1" : {
            "allOf": [{
                "$ref" : "#/$defs/AllOfField"
            },
            {
                "type" : "object",
                    "properties" : {
                    "lastTimeStampCheck" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "deprecated" : true
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "allOfField2" : {
            
            "allOf":[{
                "type" : "object",
                    "properties" : {
                    "lastTimeStampCheck" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "deprecated" : true
                    }
                }
            },
             {
                "$ref" : "#/$defs/AllOfField"
            }]
        }
    },
    
    
    "$defs" : {
        "ArbitraryField":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "description" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "AllOfField":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "description" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usually json is order-independent, unless you use an array.
Here, we find for allOfField1 and allOfField2 that there is an array specified.
Does this impact the way in which this jsd should be read, specifically the AllOfField that is rendered for the 2 cases, or should they both parse the following json:

```json
{
    "description" : "some description",
    "lastTimeStampCheck" : "10:00"
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The schema you have posted won't validate anything, the allOf will be ignored. Any valid json is valid against this schema.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of validation, it doesn't matter the order they appear in the array. `allOf` represents the boolean conjunction operation. That means it's evaluated as `validate(A) && validate(B)`. Conjunction is commutative so, `validate(A) && validate(B) == validate(B) && validate(A)`.

However, depending on the tooling you're using, annotation results may be different depending on what order you use. Annotations are keywords like `description`, `title`, etc. These don't effect validation, but assign meta-data to a value.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/$defs/foo" },
    { "description": "B" }
  ],

  "$defs": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "A"
    }
  }
}
```

Given this schema, is the description for this value "A" or "B"? It's actually both, but it's allowed for implementations that does something with annotations (such as a documentation generator) to choose between one or the other. There's no required behavior about which value a tool should use, so you'll have to read the documentation of that tool to see how it behaves. Generally, tools that choose one, consider the most recently evaluate value to override the previous values. So, I would expect the description for this value to be "B" the way I wrote this schema, but if you switch the schemas, the description would be "A". Again, that's not required behavior, but it's what I personally would find to be the least surprising behavior.